# Access to stream of ViewContext's writer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, textwriter, viewcontext

I'm writing an html helper extension for MVC5.
I need to access the ViewContext's stream to edit it.
(like a textreader)

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div>");
```

Is there any way to access the stream; so that I can manipulate or add some html code above the last "div" tag in the example ?

I was not able to find any clue about at where I can find the stream that textwriter writes to?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what view engine you are using but if you write an html helper, it will be a lot easier.  See [Creating Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Simple html helpers can be written like this:

```
@helper CustomDiv(var param1, var param2){
    Write("something to html encode & stuff");
    WriteLiteral("<div>something that is html</div>");
}
```

In Razor, You can also just call `@Write()` and it will encode the string to HTML.  If you need a TextWriter, reference `Context.Response.Output` but this will not allow you to manipulate the HTML inline like an HtmlHelper does - it's intended more for overriding the normal handler.

or just the `Output` property of `WebPageBase` which is also a TextWriter